# How can I capture and take screenshots of all the browser tabs and not only windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This class identifies all minimized windows and take a snapshot (screenshot) of them. I want to take screenshots also of all the broswer for example chrome tabs windows that are open but not in the front. Same idea that it get now the minimized windows but to get the screenshots of the broswer opened tabs ! What should I change in the WindowSnap class? Since both classes are a bit long I added them to pastebin.com

[WindowSnap.cs](http://pastebin.com/yZHkDuwk)

And this is a link for the WindowSnapColllection class:

[WindowSnapCollection.cs](http://pastebin.com/XJiANmRF)

This is how i use it in form1 to take screenshots:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add("Minimized Windows"); }));
listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true).ToArray()); }));
        }
```

In listBoxSnap i have some items when i click on item i see in a pictureBox the screenshot of the item each item is a window.

I get only minimized windows, but I want to get all the opened windows including the broswer(s) tabs !

If i set this: WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true, true) to false, false then it will take a screenshot if i open a new WINDOW in chrome ! But if i open a new TAB in chrome it won't. And i want to get all the chrome opened tabs screenshots too.

When you make right mouse click on a link in chrome you can open the link in a new TAB or a new WINDOW. If i will open it in a new window i will see this window screenshot in the listBoxSnap. But if i will open it as a new TAB it will not see the new tab screenshot .

The class WindowSnap.cs take screenshots of only windows minimized but windows not tabs !

This is how it look like when i run the program and select item in the listBox then it show on the right in the pictureBox the screenshot. But now it will show only minimized windows and if i set it to false, false it will show also broswer windows ! but NOT broswer tabs. And i want it to show also the tabs.

[image: When the program is running]

Comment: Your links to pastebin both point to collection

Comment: Thanks fixed the link for the WindowSnap.cs and to make sure i will put it also here too: http://pastebin.com/yZHkDuwk

Comment: Have you looked into Chrome extensions? There is an extension API to capture tabs: chrome.tabCapture. see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture. And review this interesting example: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/tabCapture/